# Do I need NGINX in Kubernetes for Flask/Django deployment?

Tags: django, nginx, kubernetes

So I have a bunch of flask apps and a bunch of django apps that need to be thrown onto K8s to then communicate together. Now, I understand I need a WSGI server on each of the containers I deploy. However do I need to deploy an NGINX container to forward the requests to the WSGI servers, or can I just deploy the pods containing the containers inside the service and the service will sort it out?

Answer (score 2):

no need for NGINX in this case, also you can use ingress instead https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/ to manages external access to the services (internally it uses nginx).

Comment: Ok, but how do I then manage the connections between the services?

Comment: depending on the service type you will need to read about the services types of you didn't before https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/ as an example you can make the service as clusterIP service and use the ingress to route the traffic to it then the service itself is load balancer and will route the traffic to the pods behind, simply  use ingress instead

Comment: if this still not clear let me try to prepare configuration example